# How do i run a program when my main program ends in C++

Tags: c++, exit

I need to run a program after my main program exits, is it possible to get the main program to run it on exit?

Comment: Why the at-command flag? Could you explain a bit more why you want this?

Comment: explain your question more clearly

Comment: On Posix systems you can use exec: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/exec.html. But they aren't part of standard C++.

Comment: "I need to run a program after my main program exits" - `./myProgram; ./anotherProgram`...

Comment: thanks guys, yes i want it to execute after the program terminates, i  am running it in linux, i think the script way is going to have to be the way i go.  Thank you all for comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to run something after `main` ends in a C++ program, is to do it in the destructor of a static object.

---

If you're talking about *after the program terminates*, then that is wholly outside the realm of standard C++. You'd have to use OS-specific means for that. However, the simplest then (assuming you need the whole thing to happen automatically) is to invoke your program via a command or script that runs first your program, and then the second program.

Comment: I am sorry for the poorly written question.  I did mean after the program terminates.  It will be in linux, i think the script rout will work best, thank you

Answer (score 2):

You could make a script (or again better another program) which executes the your two programs in sequence.

Comment: You can make the program run another - but I agree this is an easier solution but depends on the users actual requirements

Comment: @Mark isn't it the same of writing a program which executes two programs in sequence?

Answer (score 1):

You might find [atexit](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atexit/) useful (not sure what's your actual need). It will run the registered function just before your program ends. Note that in order for the code to run *after* your program ends, you must create a new process.

Comment: This seems to be more appropriate along the lines of : `run a program after my main program exits`.

Comment: `atexit()` is not _after_ `exit()`. Sorry this is one of the minimal requirements the OP stated in his question (even if he/she didn't explain further what _after_ should mean).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, the OP says nothing about `exit()`, and I see no point in splitting hairs about the exact semantics of `atexit` given the question is poorly defined. But if you insist, here's an exact quote from the question: _"is it possible to get the main program to run it on exit"_. `atexit` runs on exit. It can also be said that `atexit` runs _"when my program ends"_, quoting again. So `atexit` doesn't fulfill one requirement (after exit) but does fill another (on exit). Only the OP knows which one is actually desired.